# Vagrant port forwarding stops working after a while

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualization, ports

I am using an ubuntu provisioned vagrant vm to sun a service. Here is the vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision "file", source: "/opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1", destination: "/opt/"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 70
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8081, host: 7081

end
```

I then try to access the service at "localhost:7081" I can access it for sometme but then it becomes unavailable. I've tried to configure the host_ip as

```
host_ip = 127.0.0.1 and host_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

But the problem still persists

I tried destroying the VM and running the service on different ports but no luck

Comment: For me also sometime it get disconnect when my system come to sleep or suspend. Then i will reload the vagrant and it will work fine. "vagrant reload". You have to run this command from the location where Vagrantfile is present.

Comment: ya reload doesnt fix it

Comment: Please tel us more details about your machine where u have installed vargant ?